# How do I make one ui slider control all of the game audio?

Tags: unity, c#, unityscript, audio, ui-design

I use the ui slider to control how loud is the game, what I want to know is how to make one ui slider control all of the game audio?

Answer (score 1):

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/16603/is-there-a-global-volume-setting.html

Use the slider's value to determine the AudioListener.volume static field.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioListener-volume.html

It is between 0 and 1. You can get a normalised( between 0 and 1 ) value from the slider using Slider.normalizedValue.

Comment: Can you write down the code for me?

Comment: I'd like a sandwich as well Ben, while you're doing Bob's homework :) Seriously now Bob, Ben provided a very detailed answer already, show some interest in your own work, will ya...

Comment: I just checked his profile... Pretty much every question is downvoted... thats pretty impressive